# For...in loop filtering only objects

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to filter out everything inside of a for...in loop to only get the objects?

I'm writing a function to loop through nested objects to find certain pieces of data and then save it to localStorage.

Example:

```
var equipped = {
    data: [the rest of the properties of equipped go here],
    tool: {
        data: [the rest of the properties of tool go here],
        axe: {
            data: [the rest of the properties of axe go here],
            iron: {...},
            steel: {...}
        }
    }
}
```

The tool/axe/metal properties are all generated dynamically and is different each time. Inside the metal properties is the data I'm trying to save. I would normally just loop through the array if I was trying to access the data (Using knockoutjs for binding, it's much easier to just foreach the data array), but I'm using the variable from a for...in loop to build the rest of the tree in my localStorage object before stringifying it.

How I'm reading the object:

```
for (var type in equipped) {
    if (check goes here) {
        savedValue.equipped[type] = {};
        for (var category in equipped[type]) {
            etc etc...
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that everything is an object type so I can't just do an `instanceof` or `typeof` on a defined object to filter them out. Is there another easy way to do it inside of an if statement or do I have to make each step of the tree from a constructor so I can `instanceof RealObject`?

Comment: Not everything will comeback as "object" when calling `typeof`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: No, but an array will. Will I just have to do an if (typeof type === 'object' && !Array.isArray(type)) to combat this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these should do well:

```
function isObject(val) {
    if (val === null) { return false;}
    return (typeof val === 'object');
}
```

or

```
function isObject(obj) {
  return obj === Object(obj);
}
```

or
// this only works with object literals

```
function isObject(val) {
    return (!!val) && (val.constructor === Object);
};
```

this last one, gives me the following:

```
console.log(isObject()); // false
console.log(isObject([])); // false
console.log(isObject(new Date)); // false
console.log(isObject({})); // true
console.log(isObject(null)); // false
console.log(isObject(true)); // false
console.log(isObject(1)); // false
console.log(isObject('someValueString')); // false
```

so, something like:

```
for (var type in equipped) {
    if (isObject(type)) {
        savedValue.equipped[type] = {};
        for (var category in equipped[type]) {
            etc etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You can also try the following, but I have not used it. So you'd have to go thru your use cases.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf
```

Comment: I just tried both of those functions and they both return true for the data array as well. I'm trying to get only the properties that are straight up defined objects (Whether by constructor or not, doesn't matter, just as long as it's not an array/function).

Comment: ok, so - just hashes or associated arrays. I get you, hold a sec. Try that last one.

Comment: Thanks, that last one worked nicely. Can you please explain what the (!!val) does? And will this work for objects also created with a custom constructor instead of defined literally?

Comment: I just answered my own question with the custom constructors. I'm still curious how the (!!val) works though.

Comment: It's like casting to a boolean. Used to convert truthy values to boolean true, and falsy values too boolean false. At least, that is how I wrap my head around it. It's also shorter typing to generate a true/false. Another shortcut to save a byte or two on IIFE, instead of (function(){}()), do !function(){}()

Answer (score 0):

There's an old hack for type detection I've used previously.

```
var classChecker = {}.toString;
classChecker.call({});
classChecker.call(function() {});
classChecker.call([]);
// etc...

// More immediately relevant use:
var savedValue = {
  equipped: {}
};
var objectString = classChecker.call({});

for (var type in equipped) {
  if (classChecker.call(equipped[type]) === objectString) {
    savedValue.equipped[type] = {};
    for (var category in equipped[type]) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

console.log(savedValue);
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/nKLQsOdcurrpUCg7cOoJ?p=preview for a working sample. (open your console to view output)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to check whether the variable is object or not:

```js
function isJsonObject( obj ) {         
  // Must be an Object.
  // Because of IE, we also have to check the presence of the constructor property.
  // Make sure that DOM nodes and window objects don't pass through, as well
  if ( !obj || obj.toString() !== "[object Object]" || obj.nodeType || obj.setInterval ) {
   return false;
  }

  // Not own constructor property must be Object
  if ( obj.constructor
   && !obj.hasOwnProperty("constructor")
   && !obj.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("isPrototypeOf")) {
   return false;
  }

  // Own properties are enumerated firstly, so to speed up,
  // if last one is own, then all properties are own.

  var key;
  for ( key in obj ) {}

  return key === undefined || obj.hasOwnProperty( key );
 }
```